# Can I still run Ubuntu Desktop without a graphics card on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, graphics, gpu, headless

I'm a bit of a Linux noob so bear with me here!

A few years ago I set up an ubuntu desktop (I think 18.04 or maybe 16.04) to boot up and auto run a program for me with no graphics card plugged in to the motherboard. I had configured it to boot up, auto login and auto start the program with complete hands off. I remember I also had selected "ignore no VGA" for headless boot in bios so that the motherboard wouldn't freak out about no graphics card being plugged in. I have done this so I know this is not the issue.

I have done the same thing with ubuntu 20.04 today and it all works great with the card (auto login and program running) but when I pull the card out it boots and just idles. I don't need SSH or remote access and would like to just do this with ubuntu desktop again if possible. I just want to configure this once and have it do its thing when I plug it in thereafter but I cant remember if I needed to give some extra commands a few years ago for ubuntu to be able to do this or if it was maybe a feature only on older versions. Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about 20.04; so why have you tagged it as being about 16.04 & 18.04 both of which are EOSS & thus off-topic here. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS used a different desktop to 20.04, with you being unclear as to what you were using (*thus if you're comparing different desktops, or just different security issues*). GNOME desktop as used by 18.04 & 20.04 does have minimum graphics requirements (ie. video card requirements) which may not be met if card is removed; but you could always use a different desktop (*just as 16.04 used if that is what you were using; it's unclear*)

Comment: I think you should clarify.  Graphics cards are often optional on a desktop computer. 
 Motherboards have a built-in graphics card on it (i.e., your computer probably has a VGA/DVI/etc. output) even without a graphics card.  How are you removing that?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I currently have everything set up on 20.04 but its not working the same way that it did years ago. I'm not even sure which version I used years ago but I think it was 16.04 or 18.04 so that's why I mentioned those. Do you happen to know if there is a way to force 20.04 to not require a video card like the older version?  I would prefer to not have to redo everything I have done today if there's a way. thanks.

Comment: As for the second comment about the built in graphics card, my machine does not have integrated graphics on the CPU and also doesn't have built graphics on the motherboard either. It is an AMD system

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop using GNOME has requirements of a "*3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB*", "VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution" etc... If those aren't detected you **may** find GNOME won't run.  Those requirements were identical to 18.04, but were not required for 16.04 (as up to *and including Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop, a *lighter* Unity desktop was used instead of GNOME (3/4))  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: If the end goal is to run a program without a monitor attached (no graphics card) then it may be better to run the server version.

Comment: You didn't give any details about the app you want to run.  I'll try to cover them all in my answer, if I missed yours, add a description of your app to your question.

Comment: If you were using 16.04 as I suspect, you weren't using the GNOME desktop then anyway (GNOME became default with 17.10), so why not consider other *lighter* desktops like 16.04 had?  Yes the *flavor* desktop packages do not get Ubuntu Security team checks, have a shorter LTS guaranteed fix life, but otherwise go so same process.

Answer (score 1):

- Most PC motherboards require video support to POST.   This could come as integrated video in the cpu (with a hardware video port that works on the motherboard) or a video card.   If you have neither, likely the motherboard will not POST.  (Note: even if your mobo supports integrated video, the cpu must also support it to make it work.)
- Almost all embedded SOC boards either include video or include a serial port (or both), and either way don't need a video card.
- If you are running just a single application with no user interface, you don't need to run a desktop GUI at all, and it can be started via systemd.  This is the typical systemd use case for daemons.
- If you are running an application with a GUI but you don't need to interact with it, you can probably make a startx wrapper that starts xvfb or xvnc and runs the application in that with no associated video card (and no desktop apps either).
- If you do want to interact with your GUI app, you probably want xvnc with full desktop support.  This can be messy to set up, it might not work with gnome-session, but some of the simpler GUI desktops should be fine.
- If you are running an application with a text UI, it gets messy, but it is possible to run it in a disconnected `screen` session or start it on a text terminal.  The common use case for this is minecraft servers, and there are multiple questions here about how to set that up.